# The best way to fire a popup with a 10-15 sec delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have it setup as a body onLoad, but I would prefer a 15 second delay using any other function that would get the job done.

```
<body onLoad="popIt=window.open('http://www.example.com/insight',

'popIt', 'toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, menuBar=0, scrollbars=1, 

 resizable=1, width=900, height=900, left=500, top=500');">
```

What would be the best way to go about enacting a popup upon a 15 second delay?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<body onLoad="window.setTimeout(function() {popIt=window.open('url');}, 15000);">
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked the exact way I wanted it to..

Answer (score 1):

Try using setTimeout(). It can take a function and a time as arguments:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://www.example.com/insight');}, 15000);">
```

Note that the second argument to setTimeout is the time delay in milliseconds.